# Rare (intermittent) java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException in ScalaCheck

Tags: scala, exception, scalacheck

I'm getting a very rare, but repeatable, MalformedInputException in my ScalaCheck code.

I haven't been able to pin it down perfectly, or get a solid reproduction except "occasionally," but here's the code that I believe is generating the problem:

```
// Generate varying Unicode characters:
val unicodeCharacter = Gen.choose(Char.MinValue, Char.MaxValue).filter(Character.isDefined)

// Generate varying Unicode strings across all legal characters::
def unicodeGenerator(generator: Gen[Char] = unicodeCharacter, minimum: Int = 5, maximum: Int = 20): Gen[String] = Gen.chooseNum(minimum, maximum).flatMap { n =>
    Gen.sequence[String, Char](List.fill(n)(generator))
}

// The unit test that I think is occasionally blowing up:
"random strings longer than 20 characters" ! prop { (s: String) => { s.length > 20 must beTrue } }.setGen(unicodeGenerator(unicodeCharacter, 21, 30))
```

And here's the exception that I've seen:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-391" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:285)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at scala.xml.XML$.write(XML.scala:108)
    at scala.xml.XML$$anonfun$save$2.apply$mcV$sp(XML.scala:91)
    at scala.xml.XML$$anonfun$save$2.apply(XML.scala:91)
    at scala.xml.XML$$anonfun$save$2.apply(XML.scala:91)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:102)
    at scala.xml.XML$.save(XML.scala:90)
    at sbt.JUnitXmlTestsListener.writeSuite(JUnitXmlTestsListener.scala:170)
    at sbt.JUnitXmlTestsListener.endGroup(JUnitXmlTestsListener.scala:159)
    at sbt.React$$anonfun$react$8.apply(ForkTests.scala:133)
    at sbt.React$$anonfun$react$8.apply(ForkTests.scala:133)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at sbt.React.react(ForkTests.scala:133)
    at sbt.ForkTests$$anonfun$mainTestTask$1$Acceptor$2$.run(ForkTests.scala:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Internal error when running tests: sbt.ForkMain$Run$RunAborted: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

Anyone have any ideas what is causing it and **more important** how to reliably prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `JUnitXmlTestsListener` saves an XML element with `XML.save` the default encoding that is used is `ISO-8859-1`. It should use `UTF-8` instead.

You can try to remove the `JUnitXmlTestsListener` from your build and [use specs2](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6/org.specs2.guide.JUnitXmlOutput.html) to generate `junit-xml` reports:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2-junit" % "3.6"

sbt> testOnly *MySpec -- console junitxml
```

Comment: Except that I'm not generating XML or saving it. All of the code is shown above, this is probably happening deep inside ScalaCheck (I'm guessing) or Play Framework and specs2. The whole test just generates the strings, to prove that they can be generated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your stacktrace properly. This is a JUnitXmlTestListener bug then, they should use a better encoding to save their result. Maybe you can remove the listener from your sbt config and use specs2 to generate junit xml reports.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know how a JUnitXmlTestListener is getting into the mix. We are already using specs2-junit... although... is there a way we can permanently specify "console junitxml" (I'm thinking about our integration server which just runs the build.sbt test target... can we add this to build.sbt somehow?" ... I imagine I'm going to have to dig around now and find out how that listener got pulled into the mix...

Comment: There is a sbt section in the [User Guide](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#via-sbt) showing how to add arguments: `testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "console", "junitxml")`. Then I think you can remove the `JUnitXmlTestsListener` with `set testListeners := Seq()`